# c++ qt can't send data to com port

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I have very strange problem if I use this I see nothing in com port

```
QByteArray data[5], data2[1];
data->append((char)0x02);
data->append((char)0x43);
data->append((char)0x50);
data->append((char)0x03);
data->append((char)0x12);
data2->append((char)0x05);
com.write(*data);
com.readAll();
Sleep(300);
com.write(*data2);
Sleep(300);

com.close();
```

If I delete last line "com.close();" evrything works good. But I need to close com port after every command. I really don't know how to do that.

Help me please.

Comment: do not use Sleep as it blocks the Qt event loop, instead use a QTimer: change `Sleep(300); com.close();` to `QTimer::singleShot(300, &com, &QSerialPort::close);`

Comment: use serial port signals for read and write and it better to don't use sleep method

Comment: QSerialPort is buffered in Qt 5, try to call the flush() method before closing.